# Autocomplete with username and image

Tags: python, jquery, django, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete to dropdown username and user profile picture, i am getting the username correctly but profile picture is showing default images instead of the user profile picture. I do not know if i am passing this right in jquery. Here is what i have tried:

[image]

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', default="ProfilePicture/user-img.png", blank=True)
```

Views:

```
def home(request):
    all_users = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True)
    all_img = Profile.objects.all().distinct()
context = {
    'all_users': all_users,
    'all_img': all_img,
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="ui-widget"> 
 <input type="text" name="" class="autocomplete" >
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//TAG AUTOCOMPLETE FORM DROPDOWN USER NAMES
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
      {% for user in all_users %}
          "{{user|safe}}",
      {% endfor %}
  ];

  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,

}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
 var image = "<div>{% for img in all_img %}{% if img.profile_pic %}<img src='{{ img.profile_pic.url 
}}'{% endif %}{% endfor %}" + " height='55' /> " + item.label + "</div>";

return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append(image)
    .appendTo(ul);
};
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an example of you `availableTags`

Comment: @Twisty.. I have list of users in var availableTags in jquery. I make a queryset for list of users in views.py, then I included it to jquery. I am new to jquery, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There can be. Autocomplete can take a Function as a Source. In this function, it's passed `request` as an Object and `response` as a Function. This can then do an AJAX call to your Python which can build the list as a response. But the list must be correct format if it's complex data. Hence why I wanted to see an example of your `availableTags`.

Comment: @Twisty... availableTags  {% for user in all_users %} "{{user|safe}}", {% endfor %} gets all the list of users name. I am passing the queryset from views.py: all_users = User.objects.values_list('username', flat=True) to jquery. I think i do nto understand how i can do this, if you have an idea code on how i can do this successfully, you can help out with the codes. Are you familiar with Django? because I am using Django.

Comment: When you look at the View Source, what do yuo see shown in your HTML for `availableTags`.

Comment: @Twisty.. What view source? I am passing availableTags as variable, to display list of usernames when i add a text in the form.As you can see on my attached image, usernames displays correctly, but the user profile_pic is not displaying, it only shows a default image. Can you make this clearer with codes?

Comment: When you view your output, as HTML in your Browser, use View Source, to see the HTML itself. Find your JavaScript and examine the Array. What do you see?